# Adding logic to array in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have imported a CSV file and created an array out of the data. I need to split off the domain names which used split, however some of the names are IP addresses, so it is split those as well.

How can I add some logic to do my normal split? But if it's a number like a IP address, ignore and print it.

Below is my sample data, the "Client Name' is what I'm trying to work with.

```
$NewCSV = $a | ForEach-Object {
$Record = @{
    'Client Name' = $_."Name".Split('.')[0]
    'Policy Name' = $_."AgentServerType"
'Backup State' = $_."BackupStatus"
'logon' = $_."LogonAccountTestStatus"
'account' = $_."LogonAccount"
    }
New-Object PSObject -Prop $Record
} | Select "Client Name","Policy Name","Backup State","logon","account"
```

Comment: can you post the 1st few lines of the CSV so that we have something concrete to discuss? your "Below is my sample data" comment is inaccurate since that is CODE, not data. [*grin*]

Comment: Ok thanks I will keep that in mind

Comment: kool! i see that you appear to have your answer ... glad to know that you got what you needed! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the .split() method you could use the
RegEx based -split operator with a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to inhibit splitting if a digit follows.

BTW the $Record isn't meccessary.

```
$NewCSV = $a | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Prop @{
        'Client Name'  =($_.Name -split '\.(?!\d{1,3}(\.|$))')[0]
        'Policy Name'  = $_.AgentServerType
        'Backup State' = $_.BackupStatus
        'logon'        = $_.LogonAccountTestStatus
        'account'      = $_.LogonAccount
    }
} | Select "Client Name","Policy Name","Backup State",logon,account
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected result if the domain name begins with a digit.  For example, the 0th element resulting from `-split`ing `'www.23andme.com'` (no affiliation) is `'www.23andme'`.

Comment: @BACON Thanks for the hint - I extended the RegEx to exclude one to three digits and another dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`IPAddress.TryParse` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse) to determine if a `String` represents an IP address...

```
$Record = @{
    'Client Name' = if ([IPAddress]::TryParse($_.Name, [Ref] $null)) {
                        $_.Name
                    } else {
                        $_.Name.Split('.')[0]
                    }
    # ...
}
```

A type accelerator exists for the [`IPAddress` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress) so we do not need to specify the namespace, too (i.e. `[System.Net.IPAddress]`).  The second parameter of `TryParse` is used to return an `IPAddress` instance parsed from the first parameter, if successful.  We don't need this `IPAddress` instance, so we just pass `$null` instead.

Also, just a stylistic note, you don't need to and it's not typical to surround property names with quotes (e.g. `$_."AgentServerType"`) unless the property name contains whitespace.