# Regular Expressions in powershell split

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, regex-lookarounds

I need to strip out a UNC fqdn name down to just the name or IP depending on the input.

My examples would be

```
\\tom.overflow.corp.com
\\123.43.234.23.overflow.corp.com
```

I want to end up with just `tom` or `123.43.234.23`

I have the following code in my array which is striping out the domain name perfect, but Im still left with `\\tom`

```
-Split '\.(?!\d)')[0]
```

Comment: have you tried regex101.com?

Comment: @Kory Gill thank you ,nice website, I will use it more. Still have not found my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex succeeds in splitting off the tokens of interest in principle, but it doesn't account for the leading `\\` in the input strings.

You can **use regex alternation (`|`) to include the leading `\\` at the start as an *additional `-split` separator***.

Given that matching a separator at the very start of the input creates an *empty* element with index `0`, you then need to access index `1` to get the substring of interest.

In short: The regex passed to `-split` should be `'^\\\\|\.(?!\d)'` instead of  `'\.(?!\d)'`, and the index used to access the resulting array should be `[1]` instead of `[0]`:

```
'\\tom.overflow.corp.com', '\\123.43.234.23.overflow.corp.com' | 
  ForEach-Object { ($_ -Split '^\\\\|\.(?!\d)')[1] }
```

The above yields:

```
tom
123.43.234.23
```

---

**Alternatively**, you could **remove the leading `\\` in a separate step**, using `-replace`:

```
'\\tom.overflow.corp.com', '\\123.43.234.23.overflow.corp.com' | 
  ForEach-Object { ($_ -Split '\.(?!\d)')[0] -replace '^\\\\' }
```

---

Yet **another alternative** is to use a **single `-replace` operation**, which **does not require a `ForEach-Object` call** (doesn't require explicit iteration):

```
'\\tom.overflow.corp.com', '\\123.43.234.23.overflow.corp.com' -replace
  '?(x) ^\\\\ (.+?) \.\D .+', '$1'
```

- Inline option `(?x)` (`IgnoreWhiteSpace`) allows you to make regexes more readable with insignificant whitespace: any *unescaped* whitespace can be used for visual formatting.
- `^\\\\` matches the `\\` (escaped with `\`) at the start (`^`) of each string.
- `(.+?)` matches one or more characters lazily.
- `\.\D` matches a literal `.` followed by something *other* than a digit (`\d` matches a digit, `\D` is the negation of that).
- `.+` matches one or more remaining characters, i.e., the rest of the input.
- `$1` as the replacement operand refers to what the 1st capture group (`(...)`) in the regex matched, and, given that the regex was designed to consume the entire string, replaces it with just that.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @jimwood; my pleasure. As an aside: While I was personally notified of your comment due to being the author of this answer, the others who answered here were not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm stealing [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey)s `$InSTuff`
but appending a [RegEx I used recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53349759/6811411)

```
$InStuff = -split @'
\\tom.overflow.corp.com
\\123.43.234.23.overflow.corp.com
'@
$InStuff |ForEach-Object {($_.Trim('\\') -split '\.(?!\d{1,3}(\.|$))')[0]}
```

Sample Output:

```
tom
123.43.234.23
```

As you can see here on [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/pTpHv5/1) the dots between the numbers are **not** matched

Answer (score 1):

The [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) function uses regex and populates a `MatchInfo` object with the matches (which can then be queried).

The regex `"(\.?\d+)+|\w+"` works for your particular example.

```
"\\tom.overflow.corp.com", "\\123.43.234.23.overflow.corp.com" |
  Select-String "(\.?\d+)+|\w+" | % { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Answer (score 0):

while this is NOT regex, it does work. [*grin*] i suspect that if you have a really large number of such items, then you will want a regex. they do tend to be faster than simple text operators.

this will get rid of the leading `\\` and then replace the domain name with .

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = -split @'
\\tom.overflow.corp.com
\\123.43.234.23.overflow.corp.com
'@

$DomainName = '.overflow.corp.com'

$InStuff.ForEach({
    $_.TrimStart('\\').Replace($DomainName, '')
    })
```

output ...

```
tom
123.43.234.23
```

Comment: thank you. Not really what I am after, I don't want to add more code. Is '\.(?!\d)' not regex? I have got it to do almost what I want with that little bit of code. I will keep trying

Comment: @jimwood - it doesn't seem like "adding more code" from what i can see. [*grin*] the code posted by LotPings is significantly longer than what i posted. plus, my code is easily understood - regex is not quite so obvious. ///// however, if you need SPEED, then the regex method is likely the way to go.

Comment: My code will remove ***any*** trailing domain parts, while yours is fixed to a given one, so functionality counts not length. Nitpicking: mine is 75 chars/yours is ~100

Comment: @LotPings - that was not intended as any criticism of your code. i'm sorry if it seemed so, tho. [*blush*] it was a criticism of the OPs rationale for rejecting mine. [*grin*] as i mentioned, regex is almost certainly going to be faster for a large data set - if the OP has such a need. ///// i presumed the OP gave only one domain for a reason other than "oops! i should have mentioned that will change". ///// as an aside, will your regex handle `Tom.Dooley.Overflow.Corp.com`? that is why i gave up on a regex ... i could not think of any way to handle the possible pre-domain parts. [*blush*]